# Select dropdownlist issue update time on yii1

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have create dynamically dropDownList box.

1st dropbox are category and 2nd dropbox are sub category. sub category dipand on category.

create time no issue but still edit time category are selected but sub category are not selected.

All data get in single table. leval and parent_id data to manaj category.

===> my table data
| category_id | parent_id | level | category_name
|          26 |         0 |     0 | Mattresses
|          27 |         0 |     0 | Memory Foam Mattress
|          28 |         0 |     0 | Cool Beds
|         103 |        26 |     1 | Value Lines
|         104 |        26 |     1 | Firm
|         105 |        26 |     1 | Pillow Top
|         106 |        26 |     1 | Individual Wrap Coils

========> dropdown category and sub category

```
    <?php 
    $arr =  array();
     foreach($this->furniture_id as $furniture)
    {
     $id=$furniture['category_id'];
     $parent_id=$furniture['parent_id'];
      $cat_name=$furniture['category_name'];
      if($parent_id==0)
      {
    $arr[$id]=$cat_name;
      }
    } 
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'category_id');
    ?>

    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'category_id', $arr ,
    array('empty'=>'Please Select Category','onchange'=>'js:validate_dropdown(this.value)')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'category_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $images_path = realpath(Yii::app()->basePath . '/sdmattsFurniture/get_category.php'); ?>
</div></div>

 <div class="control-group" >
<div class="row">
    <?php 
    echo $form->labelEx($model,'sub_category_id'); ?>
    <?php 
    if($this->furniture_id != '')
    {
    $arr_val_sub = array();
    foreach($this->furniture_id as $furniture_sub)
    {
     $id_sub=$furniture_sub['category_id'];
     $parent_id_sub=$furniture_sub['parent_id'];
     $level=$furniture_sub['level'];
      $cat_name_sub=$furniture_sub['category_name'];
      if($parent_id_sub > 0 && $level == 0)
      {
    $arr_val_sub[$id_sub]=$cat_name_sub;
      }

    } 
    echo "<div id='sub_cat'>";
     echo $form->dropDownList($model,'sub_category_id', $arr_val_sub,
        array('empty'=>'Please Select Category','onchange'=>'js:validate_sub_dropdown(this.value)'));
    echo "</div>";?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'sub_category_id'); ?>
 <?php    } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

=====> onchange call funcation

function validate_dropdown(id)
    {

```
    id=document.getElementById('SdmattsFurniture_category_id').value;
    var sub_category_id=document.getElementById('SdmattsFurniture_sub_category_id').value;
    if(id!='Please Select Category')
    {
    xmlhttpp_div_category=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlhttpp_div_category==null)
    {
      alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
      return;
    }
    var url="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl?>/get_category.php?id="+id+"&sub_category_id="+sub_category_id;
    xmlhttpp_div_category.onreadystatechange=musicChanged_div_category;
    xmlhttpp_div_category.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttpp_div_category.send(null);
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

in case of dependent dropdownlist,i.e dorpdonw B is completely dependent on dropdown A which means initially dropdown B will b empty and when we select value in dropdown A then B will populated accordinly.If you code is working fine during addition, then i suggested you to call your function when you window is loaded
like this

```
 window.load = function(){
     id = id=document.getElementById('SdmattsFurniture_category_id').value;
     ////call your function which populate the dropdown B////
     validate_dropdown(id);
}
```